# Data link between service and component: Subject and BehaviorSubject - Need explanation

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm new to Angular and I'm stuck with Subject and BehaviorSubject concept.
Anybody can try to explain me?
I searched over the web but I can't understand how it really works. I also found Observable and Observer, but I can't understand the principle.

I understood that services are used to store global logic for few components (interaction with an API for instance) while components.ts only store the dedicated logic.

As an example, I'm trying to do a weather app with:

- weather.service.ts in which I make my get request to the API, and where I make my treatment to return an Array of object Weather (dedicated class).
- Weather.model.ts where I describe the class Weather.
- search.component.ts which is the component.

I made passed my data from weather.service.ts to search.component.ts using an Observable, I don't know if it is the good way.

weather.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Weather } from '../models/Weather.model';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WeatherService {

  APIKEY: string = "&appid=...";
  URI: string = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=";

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  getWeather(city): Observable<Weather[]> {
    //Cherche une ville dans l'API :
    return this.httpClient.get(this.URI + city + this.APIKEY).pipe(map(
      (data: any) => {
        var weatherArray: Array<Weather> = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < data.list.length; i++) {
          weatherArray.push(new Weather(
            data.list[i].dt,
            data.list[i].main.temp,
            data.list[i].main.temp_min,
            data.list[i].main.temp_max,
            data.list[i].main.feels_like,
            data.list[i].main.pressure,
            data.list[i].main.humidity,
            data.list[i].weather[0].main,
            data.list[i].weather[0].icon,
            data.list[i].clouds.all,
            data.list[i].wind.speed,
            data.list[i].wind.deg
          ));
        }
        return weatherArray;
      }
    ));
  }

}
```

Weather.model.ts

```
export class Weather {

    date: Date;
    temp: number;
    tempMin: number;
    tempMax: number;
    tempFelt: number;
    pressure: number;
    humidity: number;
    weatherDesc: string;
    weatherIcon: string;
    clouds: number;
    windSpeed: number;
    windOrientation: number;

    constructor(date: Date,
                temp: number,
                tempMin: number,
                tempMax: number,
                tempFelt: number,
                pressure: number,
                humidity: number,
                weatherDesc: string,
                weatherIcon: string,
                clouds: number,
                windSpeed: number,
                windOrientation: number) {

    }
}
```

search.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { WeatherService } from 'src/app/services/weather.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Weather } from '../../models/Weather.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-search',
  templateUrl: './search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search.component.scss']
})
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {

  searchedCity: string;
  weatherItems: Array<Weather>;

  constructor(private router: Router,
              private route: ActivatedRoute,
              private weatherService: WeatherService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    //On récupère la ville si elle y est :
    if (this.route.snapshot.params['city']) {
      this.searchedCity = this.route.snapshot.params['city'];
      this.weatherService.getWeather(this.searchedCity).subscribe(
        (data) => {
          this.weatherItems = data;
        }, (err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    } 
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct and no need to use `BehaviorSubject` or `Subject` in this case.

For better understanding of the differences see this https://coryrylan.com/blog/rxjs-observables-versus-subjects

But in brief, this is Observable, and observer

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

const observable = new Observable(observer => {
  setTimeout(() => observer.next('hello from Observable!'), 1000);
});

observable.subscribe(v => console.log(v));
```

and Subjects are inherited form Observable and are like

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

const subject = new Subject();

subject.next('missed message from Subject');

subject.subscribe(v => console.log(v));

subject.next('hello from subject!');
```

pay attention you can call `next` on subject , (you need to do the same via observer in observable)

also till now you can't access latest value submitted, so `BehaviorSubject` is for that, it's inherited from `Subject` and has the value, also the time you instantiate it will emit the first value in the constructor

```
import { ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs';

const behaviorSubject = new BehaviorSubject(
  'hello initial value from BehaviorSubject'
);

behaviorSubject.subscribe(v => console.log(v));

behaviorSubject.next('hello again from BehaviorSubject');
```

Both `Subject` and `BehaviorSubject` has `complete` menu to end the subscription.

also the time you subscribe to `BehaviorSubject` it will emit the latest value.

### Code Improvement

regarding your code there are some improvement as below

weather.model.ts

```
export interface Weather {

    date: Date;
    temp: number;
    tempMin: number;
    tempMax: number;
    tempFelt: number;
    pressure: number;
    humidity: number;
    weatherDesc: string;
    weatherIcon: string;
    clouds: number;
    windSpeed: number;
    windOrientation: number;

}
```

service

```
getWeather(city): Observable<Weather[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get(`${this.URI}${city}${this.APIKEY}`)
      .pipe(
         map((data: any) => data.list.map(item => ({
            date: item.dt,
            temp: item.main.temp,
            tempMin: item.main.temp_min,
            tempMax: item.main.temp_max,
            tempFelt: item.main.feels_like,
            pressure: item.main.pressure,
            humidity: item.main.humidity,
            weatherDesc: item.weather[0].main,
            weatherIcon: item.weather[0].icon,
            clouds: item.clouds.all,
            windSpeed: item.wind.speed,
            windOrientation: item.wind.deg
         }))
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I think I had better understood right now. I need to train me on few examples to better understand. Is that a good practice to use Observable like my example for get requests in a service?

Comment: @Fred Yes, approach is good, but code can be better, let me update my answer

Comment: I understand the improvements in service. About the class vs interface, you advice an interface instead of a class because I have no methods inside, and I use only Weather class to define the structure of my object, that's right? Thanks a lot for your help and your answers already done!